# how to change the color that's used for transparency automatically, or programmatically?

Tags: gimp, imagemagick, transparency, image-transparency

For every picture (e.g. bmp, png), a transparent point actually **does have a color**

The transparency is either

- defined by alpha channel mask (e.g. in PNG)
- or one of the colors is defined as transparent, and the viewer program is responsible to replace pixels with this color - as transparent.

I have a strange scenario, where one program knows transparency, the other doesn't so it shows the original color.

So

I want to replace the color only in the pixels where it is defined to be transparent. I need it all to be defined as white, while keeping it transparent

I can pre-convert my input to be a specific format, if it helps the process.

For now my toolbox includes: ImageMagick, Gimp, python programming (PIL) and maybe more, but I don't know how to do this specific task with these tools.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 convert infile -fill white -opaque none outfile
```

Comment: no: it deletes the transparency - i want to keep transparency, but replace the color behind it! I rephrased my question. תודה בכל אופן.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11398) will help.